# OnClickListener not working for TextView in Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I have a Fragment that has a TextView that should redirect to another Activity when clicked. I implemented the OnClickListener for the TextView "empty" but it is not working. I put a System.out to print something when clicked and it is not even printing it.

This is my fragment:

```
public class OrderFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private BeeGif viewGif;
    private ListView lstChefOrders;
    private ArrayList<OrderList> orderLists, listOrders;
    private TextView empty;

    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order, null, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        empty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.empty);
        lstChefOrders = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lstChefOrders);
        lstChefOrders.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        RelativeLayout viewLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.beeGifOrder);
        viewGif = (BeeGif) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.view);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                if (NetworkHelper.isOnline(getActivity())) {
                    callOrderService();
                } else {
                    NetworkHelper.noNetworkToast(getActivity());
                }
            }
        });

        if (NetworkHelper.isOnline(getActivity())) {
            if (!PrefernceHelper.getBoolean(getActivity(), Commons.Constants.USERLOGGEDIN)) {

                lstChefOrders.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                empty.setText(R.string.order_history);

                empty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        System.out.println("Teste");
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setClass(getActivity(), SignInActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                });

            } else {
                lstChefOrders.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewGif.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                callOrderService();
            }
        } else
            NetworkHelper.noNetworkToast(getActivity());
    }


    private void callOrderService() {
        //  Log.e("TAG", "Kuch toh patta chala : " + PrefernceHelper.getString(getActivity(), Commons.Constants.USER_ID));

        new VolleyHelper(getActivity()).get("foodiesOrderListing/" + PrefernceHelper.getString(getActivity(), Commons.Constants.USER_ID), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                viewGif.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                //  Log.e("TAG", "Thanks for the return GIFT : " + response.toString());
                try {
                    // HashMap<String, List<OrderList>> listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<OrderList>>();
                    ArrayList<OrderId> orderIdList = new ArrayList<>();
                    orderLists = new ArrayList<>();
                    listOrders = new ArrayList<>();

                    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("order_ids");

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        String status = "";
                        OrderList orderList1 = new OrderList();
                        OrderId orderId = new OrderId();
                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        String date = object.getString("order_date");
                        orderId.setOrder_date(date);
                        orderId.setOrderid(object.getString("orderid"));
                        orderIdList.add(orderId);

                        //orderList1.setOrder_status("Pending");
                        orderList1.setOrderid(object.getString("orderid"));
                        orderList1.setChef_id("");
                        orderList1.setUser_id("");
                        orderList1.setItem_id("");
                        orderList1.setItem_qty("");
                        orderList1.setItem_price("");
                        orderList1.setItem_name(object.getString("orderid"));
                        orderList1.setOrderDate(object.getString("order_date"));

                        if (i % 2 == 0) {
                            orderList1.setBackGroundColor(Commons.Constants.TYPE_WHITE);
                        } else {
                            orderList1.setBackGroundColor(Commons.Constants.TYPE_GREY);
                        }
                        //listOrders.add(orderList1);


                        JSONArray orderListArray = response.getJSONArray("orderList");
                        for (int j = 0; j < orderListArray.length(); j++) {
                            OrderList orderList = new OrderList();
                            JSONObject orderListObject = orderListArray.getJSONObject(j);
                            if (orderIdList.get(i).getOrderid().equals(orderListObject.getString("orderid"))) {

                                status = orderListObject.getString("order_status");
                                //orderList.setOrder_status(orderListObject.getString("order_status"));
                                //orderList.setOrderid(orderListObject.getString("orderid"));
                                //orderList.setChef_id(orderListObject.getString("chef_id"));
                                //orderList.setUser_id(orderListObject.getString("user_id"));
                                //orderList.setItem_id(orderListObject.getString("item_id"));
                                //orderList.setItem_qty(orderListObject.getString("item_qty"));
                                //orderList.setItem_price(orderListObject.getString("item_price"));
                                //orderList.setItem_name(orderListObject.getString("orderid"));
                                //orderList.setOrderDate(date);
                                /*if (j % 2 == 0) {
                                    orderList.setBackGroundColor(Commons.Constants.TYPE_WHITE);
                                } else {
                                    orderList.setBackGroundColor(Commons.Constants.TYPE_GREY);
                                }
                                orderLists.add(orderList);*/
                            }

                        }
                        orderList1.setOrder_status(status);
                        listOrders.add(orderList1);

                        // listDataChild.put(orderId.getOrder_date(), orderLists);

                    }

                    if (listOrders.size() > 0) {
                        OrderListAdapter adapter = new OrderListAdapter(getActivity(), listOrders); //listDataChild (was the 3rd paramter for the Constructor earlier)
                        lstChefOrders.setAdapter(adapter);
                        empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        if (getView().findViewById(R.id.empty) != null)
                            lstChefOrders.setEmptyView(getView().findViewById(R.id.empty));
                        // for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getGroupCount(); i++)
                        //    lstChefOrders.expandGroup(i);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException je) {

                }catch (NullPointerException npe){
                    npe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getActivity(), OrderDetailsActivity.class);
        //intent.putExtra("orderID", orderLists.get(position).getOrderid());
        intent.putExtra("orderID", listOrders.get(position).getOrderid());
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

And this is the XML for the fragment with the textView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No Orders placed"
        android:textColor="@color/toolbar_title_color"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchText"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".NearbyJobsActivity$PlaceholderFragment">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lstChefOrders"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_five"
            android:divider="@color/line_color"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_five"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


    <include
        android:id="@+id/beeGifOrder"
        layout="@layout/view_bee_animation"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/size_of_bee_gif"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_of_bee_gif"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I can't see BindView in your class, have you implemented it??

Comment: Can you add log statement before setting onClickListener? And see whether it is being printed or not?

Comment: What is BindView? I have other onclicklisteners in my project but they all work. I have problems with only this one.

Answer (score 1):

You don't bind the click listener to the text view if those conditions are false:

```
    if(NetworkHelper.isOnline(getActivity())) {
        if (!PrefernceHelper.getBoolean(getActivity(), Commons.Constants.USERLOGGEDIN))
```

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. Can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: For example if this happens at onViewCreated: 

* NetworkHelper.isOnline(getActivity()) == false * , 

then the "empty" text view won't have a click listener attached to it. Try a more logical approach, meaning to perform the check for network connections and anything  else you need inside the listener.

Comment: Okay, making myself more clear: onViewCreated() is called when the fragment view was created. If in that moment, the code inside those "if" statements is not executed the listener won't be "attached" to the text view. Making some sense?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I understood what you said. But I put the the onClickListener outside those if's just to see if it would work but it didn't work too. So I don't know if the problem is that.

Comment: Even so, are you sure the if conditions are true?

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
empty.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.order_history));
empty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Teste", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that but nothing is being printed.

Comment: If its in a fragment,  replace getbasecontext() with getContext(), replace 'this' with get context() and startActivity() with get context().startActivity()